# Mac 10.5.8 Leopard

Tags: mac

I have a Mac 10.5.8, Leopard, gray surrounding, and cannot get on skype and I cannot create a customized header with iPhoto for Twitter. I'm not a tech person but am good with apps. How do you know you have the system requirements to upgrade to 9 and will that allow me to get skype, etc.

iMac Model Identifier: iMac8,1 Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz Number Of Processors: 1 Total Number Of Cores: 2 L2 Cache: 6 MB Memory: 2 GB

Comment: With only 2GB of RAM upgrading to OS X Yosemite 10.10.x will run somewhat slow under heavy workloads.  On an iMac 20: early 2008 the RAM can be upgraded to 4 GB and that would be much better.

Comment: I have a iMac7,1 with 4 GB of memory. I have no problem running OS X 10.10.3 or Windows 8.1. It would be worth upgrading the memory. I have not tried Skype so I can not report how well that app will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your iMac (8,1) can be updated to the latest version of OS X (currently 10.10.3).

However, since you have Leopard (10.5), you will need Snow Leopard (10.6) in order to update to any newer OS X version over the internet.

[You can buy Snow Leopard from Apple for $20 here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard).

Comment: with only 2GB of RAM might be close call to run Yosemite.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, OS X 10.10 SR calls for 2 GB RAM and it will install and run, albeit slowly, on 2GB RAM.  The Early 2008 iMac can be upgraded to 4 GB RAM and run better. (Which I've already mentioned in the comments under the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft (that now owns Skype)

> Skype no longer supports Mac OSX 10.5 (Leopard) and below.

So you have to upgrade your OS X to next version or higher.

For OS X 10.6–10.8 use  Skype for Mac 6.15

For latest Skype you need minimum OS X Mavericks or latest Yosemite.

Going above 10.6 (Snow Leopard) it is highly recommended to do memory upgrade from now 2 GB to 4 GB.

Memory upgrade is not big challenge and it can be done by you.

It does involves opening the computer and replacing hardware.

My recommendation would be you go for the [Snow Leopard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) (without memory upgrade) and give it a test run with Skype version downloaded from here:

http://download.skype.com/macosx/Skype_6.15.0.335.dmg

What do you [need and how to upgrade to Snow Leopard.](https://www.apple.com/support/snowleopard/installation/)

Once you are on Snow Leopard you can easily (for free) upgrade to Yosemite if you want to, and also get latest Skype, but it might be slow if you do not upgrade memory.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to find an old version of skype from http://www.oldapps.com/mac/skype.php that might meet your needs. Failing an (older) upgrade solves your issue, you best bet is to upgrade to you computer as mentioned in other answers. I would like to add your money will be better spent on a SSD than ram in terms of cost over performance, but upgrading both ram and your hard drive is the best option.

Comment: I think the Skype servers will no longer accept connections from older clients.